# Send both POST and GET parameters in Django test client

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I've created a view created in Django which accepts both GET and POST parameters. When trying to test it using `django-rest-framework` test `APIClient`, it's not clear how I can send both GET and POST parameters.

`self.client.post` has a signature as follows:

```py
self, path, data=None, format=None, content_type=None,
             follow=False, **extra
```

Using `data` would probably send POST data, is there any workarounds for this?

Comment: You can use only one method in request. If method is GET, send query params, and if its POST then send the payload with it.

Comment: A GET request [can have a body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body), although this is unusual.